# Show 3 randomly picked statements

Tags: javascript, html

Im currently designing a website and trying to get it to randomly show 3 statements from a list of a few. Ive managed to search and find the following code, but it only displays one thing at a time, how could I modify this to show 3 different items from the list (on seperate lines)?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>whynot?</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var textarray = [
 "why not play some fifa?",
 "why not open a beer?",
 "why not call a relative?",
 "why not challenge someone to a duel?"
];

function RndText() {
  var rannum= Math.floor(Math.random()*textarray.length);
  document.getElementById('ShowText').innerHTML=textarray[rannum];
}

onload = function() { RndText(); }

</script>
</body>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFF00">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">
            &nbsp;</h1>
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">
        &nbsp;</h1>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">
        <span style="color:#000000;"><span style="font-family: 'lucida sans unicode', 'lucida grande', sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 36px;"><span style="line-height: 16px;"><span style="background-color:#ffff00;">
<div id="ShowText"></div></span></span></span></span></span></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can put multiple CSS declarations in the `style` attribute of a single element - you don't have to have one `<span>` per. Ideally you should use separate CSS for a class, then specify the class on that `<span>`, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/TkPW6/) out, this will give you three `distinct` statements from the `array`.

```
function RndText() 
{
  var x=[];
  while(x.length !== 3)
  {
  var rannum= Math.floor(Math.random()*textarray.length);

   if(x.indexOf(rannum) === -1)
    {
  x.push(rannum);
  document.getElementById('ShowText').innerHTML += textarray[rannum] + "<br> <br> <br>";

    }

   }
}
```

UPDATE: [**New Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/TkPW6/1/)

Comment: Is there a way to number them 1. 2. and 3.?

Comment: @user1045280 so you want to prefix the sentence with 1. 2. 3..?

Comment: If that's what you meant, that's extremely easy.

Answer (score 0):

Simply execute the RndText(); function 3 times:

```
onload = function() { RndText();RndText();RndText(); }
```

and:

```
function RndText() {
  var rannum= Math.floor(Math.random()*textarray.length);
var item=document.getElementById('ShowText');
  item.innerHTML=item.innerHTML+textarray[rannum];
}
```

Comment: @LucianDepold: downvote nullified, I don't see why that was needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
function RndText() {
    for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
        var rannum= Math.floor(Math.random()*textarray.length);
        document.getElementById('ShowText').innerHTML += textarray[rannum];
   }
}
```

You need the `+=` on `innerHTML` for it to show 3 different ones.

Answer (score 0):

This expands upon the above answer by Rajaprabhu and adds the statements into the three separate spans.

Check out the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/talymo/7VNFM/

```
var textarray = [
    "why not play some fifa?",
    "why not open a beer?",
    "why not call a relative?",
    "why not challenge someone to a duel?"];


function RndText() {
    var x = [];
    var html = '';   
    while (x.length !== 3) {
        var rannum = Math.floor(Math.random() * textarray.length);
        if (x.indexOf(rannum) === -1) {
            console.log(x.length);
            x.push(rannum);
            $('#Phrase'+ x.length).html(textarray[rannum]);
        }
    }

}
```